# how to defined a function in rails 3 and how to call it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new at rails 3 can you tell me how to defined a function in rails 3?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're asking... You don't really just define a function and then go on your merry way...  Do you understand how the framework works together?

Rails (all rails, not just 3) has a model, a view, and a controller (roughly speaking) that all work together to display a web page.  The model describes an object (like a User), the controller describes things you can do with the user (usually CRUD: Create, Read, Update, Destroy) and the view describes how display the user (for example, an html page).

If you wanted to put a function (called "methods" in ruby) in your model, you could do something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def my_method
     return "Hello World"
  end

end
```

If you wanted to call your method, you would need an actual individual user to call it on.  For example you could do something like:

```
u = User.create()
u.my_method
```

If you wanted the method to apply to all users, not just a single User, you could do a class variable instead, like:

```
def User.class_method

end
```

and call it like User.class_method.

Hope this helps...there's a LOT of tutorials out on the web you can look through.